# C++ can't read from file properly

Tags: c++, windows, c++11, visual-c++, c++14

Why C++ doesn't read the text properly? Even if I enter one of the names shown in the picture below, it writes "wrong name". Looke below for the screenshot

[image]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
ifstream data_base;
data_base.open("database.txt", ios::out);

string name, a;
int b, c, d, e, test=0;

system ("cls");
cout<<"enter name "<<endl;
cin>>name;

while (data_base >> a >> b >> c >> d >> e){
    if (name == a) test=1;
}

if (test!=1)
cout<<"wrong name"<<endl;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does "doesn't read the text properly" mean? What did you input and what did you expect to happen and what actually happened? Also, please paste your code into the question instead of posting links to images.

Comment: Please edit your question to contain [mcve]. Note your code should be posted as text, nobody is going to convert image to text to check your program and compilers do not accept images.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code and input or output. Post that as *text* *in* the question.

Comment: You have enough reputation to copy your text and paste it into the question. Everyone does.

Comment: `if (str == ..) ` sure fail

Comment: I've posted the code too

Comment: I don't understand.  You are using an *input* file stream, `std::ifstream`, but you are specifying the mode as output.  If you want to read and write to the same file, open with `fstream` and use `ios::in | ios::out`.

Comment: Prefer to use the modern `bool` type for yes/no or `true/false` values.  Using `1` and `0` is so archaic (think around 1960's).

Answer (score -2):

Try the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream data_base;
    data_base.open("database.txt", ios::out);

    string name, a;
    int b, c, d, e, test = 0;

    system ("cls");
    cout << "enter name ";
    cin >> name;

    while (data_base >> a >> b >> c >> d >> e)
    {
        if (name == a)
        {
            test = 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (test!=1)
        cout << "wrong name" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: Even if I reach the right name, the program does not recognise it...still getting "wrong name"